# How to get RavenDB to recognize a plugin?

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying setup the Versioning bundle in RavenDB: http://ravendb.net/bundles/versioning

The installation instructions are pretty straight forward:

> Simply place the Raven.Bundles.Versioning.dll in the Plugins
>   directory.

I've tried this do this by creating a "Plugins" directory under the Server directory (the Server directory contains the Raven.Server.exe), and dropping Raven.Client.Versioning.dll into that Plugins directory.

However, when I run RavenDB after that (either from the command line or as a service), it doesn't give me any indication that it has recognized the plugin, and when I save/edit new documents no versioning is being applied.

I've tried running with the default plugin directory settings (which supposedly automatically looks in the Plugins directory), and I've tried manually adding the PluginsDirectory setting to Raven.Server.exe.config, to no avail.

Has anyone been able to get plugins working, specifically the versioning bundle?  Do you hae to do anything special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike,
It is supposed to just work. Take a look at the statistics, you should see the versioning trigger registered there.

It is important to ensure that:

- You are using the same version of the dlls
- You restarts RavenDB after copying the directory
- You don't reference another Raven/PluginsDirectory in the configuration

It is probably better to follow this up in the [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/).

Comment: Thanks Ayende.  I downloaded the latest build this morning to make sure I had the same versions for everything, and that got it working.

Comment: I've similar problem - how do I look at the statistics? Sorry for such a basic question. I'm running in debug mode (just the distributed exe) and there's no mention in the log that scrolls past...

Answer (score 1):

For Raven v2, you'll also add the bundle name to the the Raven/ActiveBundles property on a database document. The names should be semicolon-delimited.

For example, I have a database called MidwestAnimalRescue. To enable the [Periodic Backup](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/studio/bundles/periodicbackup) bundle and the [Versioning](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/versioning) bundle, my document will look like this:

[image]